# how to make content responsive in polymer?

Tags: css, responsive-design, polymer

I have a problem dealing with responsive UI in polymer, when the browser is stretched or narrow, content will auto adjust its width，but mine isn't.

Polymer website:

**full width:**
[image]

**narrow width:**

[image]

**but mine is:**

[image]

**code:**

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-scroll-header-panel/core-scroll-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-scroll-threshold/core-scroll-threshold.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-item/core-item.html">
<polymer-element name="catalog-layout" attributes="category toast">
  <template>
    <style shim-shadowdom>
      html,
      body {
        font-family: "RobotoDraft", sans-serif;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
        tap-highlight-color: transparent;
        background-color: #fafafa;
        font-weight: 300;
        height: 100%;
      }
      body {
        margin: 0;
        color: #333;
      }
      core-scroll-header-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #eee;
      }
      /* background for toolbar when it is at its full size */
      core-scroll-header-panel::shadow #headerBg {
        background: #5cebca;
      }
      /* background for toolbar when it is condensed */
      core-scroll-header-panel::shadow #condensedHeaderBg {
        background-color: #f4b400;
      }
      core-toolbar {
        color: #f1f1f1;
        fill: #f1f1f1;
        background-color: transparent;
      }
      .title {
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0;
        transform-origin: 0;
        font-size: 40px;
      }
      .contentcontainer {
        word-wrap: break-word;
        padding: 8px;
      }
      /*.contentcontainer{
          margin-top:40px;
          height:100%;
        }*/
    </style>
    <core-ajax id="catalogajax" auto method="GET" params='{"offset":{{offset}}}' headers='{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}' url="http://farefair.com:8888/api/v1/article/catalog" handleAs="json" response="{{response}}"></core-ajax>
    <core-scroll-header-panel id="scrollpanel" condenses="true" keepCondensedHeader scrollAwayTopbar="false">
      <core-toolbar class="tall">
        <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
        <div flex></div>
        <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
        <div id="title" class="bottom indent title">{{category}}</div>

      </core-toolbar>
      <div layout vertical flex id="catalogcontainer" class="contentcontainer">
        <template repeat="{{articlecatalog in articlecatalogs}}">
          <div layout horizontal class="rowcontent">
            <div flex></div>
            <div flex three>
              <!-- <core-selector> -->
              <div style="border: 1px solid #bebebe; padding: 16px; margin: 16px; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #fff; color: #555;">
                <!-- <div style="display: inline-block; height: 64px; width: 64px; border-radius: 50%; background: #ddd; line-height: 64px; font-size: 30px; color: #666; text-align: center;">A</div> -->
                <div style="font-size: 22px; padding: 8px 0 16px; color: #888;"><a href="/article/{{category}}/{{articlecatalog.title}}">{{articlecatalog.title}}</a>
                </div>
                <div style="font-size: 16px; padding-bottom: 8px;">ccccccccccccasdsadsadsadscccccccccccccccccccccc</div>
                <div style="font-size: 12px;">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbasdsabbbbbbbbbbbsadsadsbbdsasadsadsadsdsbbbbbbbb</div>
                <div style="font-size: 12px;">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaad aaaaaaaaaaaaasadssdsadsadsdsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
              </div>
              <!-- </core-selector> -->
            </div>
            <div flex></div>
          </div>
        </template>
      </div>
    </core-scroll-header-panel>

    <!-- <content class="content"></content> -->
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('catalog-layout', {
      domReady: function() {
        this.offset = 0;
        this.articlecatalogs = {};
        var titleStyle = this.$.title.style;
        this.addEventListener('core-header-transform', function(e) {
          var d = e.detail;
          var m = d.height - d.condensedHeight;
          var scale = Math.max(0.75, (m - d.y) / (m / 0.25) + 0.75);
          titleStyle.transform = titleStyle.webkitTransform =
            'scale(' + scale + ') translateZ(0)';
        });
        var ajax = this.$.catalogajax;
        that = this;
        this.articlecatalogs = [];
        ajax.addEventListener("core-response", function(e) {
          if (this.response == null) {} else {
            that.articlecatalogs = that.articlecatalogs.concat(this.response);
          }
        });
        scrollpanel = this.$.scrollpanel;
        scrollpanel.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
          if (e.detail.target.scrollTop >= e.detail.target.scrollHeight - e.detail.target.offsetHeight - 100) {
            that.offset += 10;
          }
        });
      },

    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

What is the trickyin polymer, how to use polymer features to accomplish this?

Comment: I thought all Polymer elements were responsive by default.

Comment: yeah,i think the same as you,but what is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

core-media-query is what you are looking for. https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-media-query.html

```
<core-media-query query="max-width: 640px" queryMatches="{{phoneScreen}}"></core-media-query>
```

with the line above if the page size is smaller then 640px then phoneScreen would be true. you could pair that with conditional templates to change the look of the page depending on page width.

```
<template if="{{phoneScreen}}">
  // do something to page when small 
</template>

<template if="{{!phoneScreen}}">
  // do something to page when big
</template>
```

here is a video going over how to use it. if i can help anymore just let me know.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svfu9iQ8cyg

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a css problem try adding

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

to your class the reason is because all your words are on one line and there is no-spacing in between them so they are not breaking to the next line also make sure that you do not have a specific height set on the your tiles if you need to set a height set a min-height. Hopefully this points you in the right direction its hard to trouble shoot with out some code to play with!

Comment: Mr,Save the day.your method perfectly worked,but i have edited my question,and paste my code there,please look at where i did wrong,also check out this sample in [link](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/core-scroll-header-panel/demo.html),i didnt find any css to adjust the width.